# Tensorflow object detection API:Sample program not working as expected

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am running sample program which comes packaged with Tensorflow object detection API(object_detection_tutorial.ipynb).
Program runs fine with no error, but bounding boxes are not diaplayed at all.

[image]

My environment is as follows:

Windows 10

Python 3.6.3

What can be the reason?

With regards

Manish

Comment: I also have the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237388/nothing-is-being-detected-tensorflow-object-detection-api

Comment: Please upvote here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2773

Comment: Can you say what version of Tensorflow you are running?

Comment: Tensorflow version is 1.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try updated SSD models in the detection zoo : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md. This should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the latest version of the model `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_08` doesn't work and outputs abnormally low value. Replacing it in the Jupyter Notebook with an older version of the model works fine for me:

```
# What model to download.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_11_06_2017'
```

Ref: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2773