# Tensorflow object_detection does not create boxes, Scores for classes are so weak

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

I run tensorflow object_detection api last week correctly on my webcam (in windows). But this week after tensorflow updated to 1.4.0 it compiled correctly but it did not create boxes even for its test images. Since I did not have tensorflow 1.4.0 source files for windows platform, I run it on my ubuntu but the result is the same, boxes do not created.
I saw my variables in spyder IDE, the scores for detected classes are so weak. Why this happened? Am I run it wrong?
Thanks for your helps guys ...

Comment: Do you have a code exmaple ?

Comment: Yes this is the [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb)

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237388/nothing-is-being-detected-tensorflow-object-detection-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug with tensorflow last update. I mentioned it in github and it solved. this is the [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2781)